# Floating Point multiplication in custom commands

Tags: macros, calculations

I'd like to create a custom command which creates an underscore of a given length. However, this length should be the argument of the command multiplied be a floating point constant.

How can I multiply the argument of a command within the command's definition?

The code without the multiplication looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\utext}[2]{$\underset{\mbox{\tiny #1}}{\underline{\hspace{#2cm}}}$}
```

Instead of the `\hspace` of `#2cm` it should be something like `(0.75 * #2)cm`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways for solving the problem.

First (and recommended):

```
\newlength{\threequarters}
\setlength{\threequarters}{0.75cm}

\newcommand{\utext}[2]{%
  $\underset{\mbox{\tiny #1}}{\underline{\hspace{#2\threequarters}}}$%
}
```

In this way, `#2` can be any decimal number.

Second, trickier:

```
\newcommand{\utext}[2]{%
  $\underset{\mbox{\tiny #1}}{\underline{\hspace{0.75\dimexpr#2cm\relax}}}$%
}
```

Why do I recommend the first way? You can use `\threequarters` wherever you want and change its width by acting just in one place, instead of looking for `0.75` across your definitions.

However, also the second solution is "parametrisable", by doing

```
\newcommand{\threequarterfactor}{0.75}
```

and using `\hspace{\threequarterfactor\dimexpr#2cm\relax}` in the definition. I still prefer reserving a length.

Comment: I suppose I'd better upvote this one for being even less wrong than my answer:-)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for a mathematical use, here is a command that can  do the calculation with an accuracy of 18 decimal places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\utext}[2]{
  \FPmul\result{.75000001}{#2}
  $\underset{\mbox{\tiny #1}}{\underline{\hspace{\result  cm}}}$}

\utext{test}{1.9809997889999999} \result

\utext{test}{1.9809997889999990} \result
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since I'm only calculating the length of the underscore, I won't need that much precision. This will be handy, when working with mathematical expressions though. Thanks